# How to download webpage from url as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to download JSON from a URL as a string, like a `DownloadString()` method in C#.

I'm not sure how to do it.
I need something like that:

```
var abc=DownloadString("url");
var myBooks = JSON.parse(abc);
```

It's my first day with JS and jQuery. I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but i need to solve it fastly

Comment: Look into promises, async/await (promises written more procedurally), and the Web API “fetch”.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
async function getBooks() {
    var abc = await fetch("file.json");
    var myBooks = await abc.json()
}
```

Comment: fetch returns a promise that resolves to a Response object, it is not a string and cannot be JSON.parsed. You should use  the json method of the response object